# Connecting a C++ Program to an Access Database

Tags: c++, database, ms-access

I am quite new to C++. I have a project to make in which I have to connect a C++ Program to a Microsoft Access Database. So this is what I have to do:

1. Make the Access Database ( I can do this.)
2. Connect the Database with C++ Forms Program ( This is what I need help in.)

So I just want to know three things.

1. What should I use in the program itself to show the records, data, etc. ( What control?)
2. How to link the database to the program.
3. What methods can I use? ( get record, delete record, query, etc)

Comment: You'd have a *much* easier time doing this from C# instead of C++, if you have that option.

Comment: You'd have a *much* easier time doing this using sqlite, if you have that option.

Comment: If you can, use any other language (PERL, PHP, C#, Java, VB) for database access simply because database coding in C++ requires a ton of error checking (which can easily be screwed up, especially by a newbie) that the fore-mentioned languages handle for you.  If it has to be in C++, are you using managed C++ or standard C++?

Comment: @user519653: Have a look at [*this page*](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/189148/).