# Linking MS Access Database with Visual Studio 2005 Windows Form Application

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, connection

Im programming in C++. And need to store data into database made in MS Access. How can i establish the connection and store and retrieve data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting a C++ Program to an Access Databse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691425/connecting-a-c-program-to-an-access-databse)

Answer (score 0):

Used to be ODBC; now I'm not so sure.  [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xweb/archive/2010/03/29/using-an-access-2007-database-with-asp-net-3-5-and-expression-web-3.aspx) might affect your direction.